# Would moving a dwarf's bedroom give it an unhappy thought?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'd assume not having a place to sleep would give it one. What about if there was a new room already made? I have seen dwarves become attached to weapons... can they become attached to furniture?

Comment: I've seen clothing as well, but I've never seen furniture, and certainly not space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dwarves are fickle enough as is, sometimes ignoring assigned rooms to sleep in the hospital, or barracks. **Dwarves do not get attached to furniture.**

One important bedroom-related function is jealousy -- nobles get jealous if they perceive a "lesser" dwarf having better holdings than their own.

Comment: Actually, Today fixed the sleeping bugs a couple versions ago. They should sleep in the proper places now...